# is the WPF Toolkit part of WPF 4.0

Tags: wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

The last time there was a release of WPF toolkit (according to the codeplex page) was in February of 2010.

So since then has the the WPF toolkit been incorporated into WPF?

I recently installed visual studio 2010 and starting developing in .net4.0 and everything that comes with it.

A few of the old WPF projects that I had developed in vs2008 refused to build until I weeded out all references to the WPF Toolkit and its controls.
I assumed that that was because it had been incorporated into WPF proper and therefore was conflicting somehow.

I did see that some controls (DataGrid, DatePicker, etc.) seem to have been included.

However I cant find all of the controls (autocomplete, etc.).

Also if the toolkit is just a bunch of controls and resources for including in your project. Why does it need to be installed on the development computer with an msi? Wouldn't it make more sense to distribute it as DLLs that could be referenced by you project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AutoComplete textbox is a component which is in the [Preview Quality Band](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quality%20Bands) in the WPF Toolkit .So it is not available is visualstudio 2010.